# Accessing window object in Ionic 2 / Angular 2 beta 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In Angular 1.x and Ionic 1.x I could access the window object through dependency injection, like so:

```
angular.module('app.utils', [])

.factory('LocalStorage', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        set: function(key, value) {
          $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },
        get: function(key, defaultValue) {
          return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can I do the same in Angular 2 & Ionic 2?

Comment: using **window** same as you would in plain javascript?

Comment: alternatively you could make a service wrapping the window object. So you can more easily mock it in tests.

Comment: @toskv Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Yes. I want to know how we can make a service wrapping the window object.

Comment: I edited @sebaferreras 's answer with a naive example. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `window` object without importing anything, but by just using it in your typescript code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
     templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  public foo: string;

  constructor() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');

    this.foo = window.localStorage.getItem('foo');
  }
}
```

You could also wrap the `window` object inside a service so then you can mock it for testing purposes.

A naive implementation would be:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
  public window = window;
}
```

You can then provide this when bootstrapping the application so it's available everywhere.

```js
import { WindowService } from './windowservice';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [WindowService]);
```

And just use it in your components.

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { WindowService } from "./windowservice";

@Component({
     templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  public foo: string;

  constructor(private windowService: WindowService) {
    windowService.window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');

    this.foo = windowService.window.localStorage.getItem('foo');
  }
}
```

A more sophisticated service could wrap the methods and calls so it's more pleasant to use.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @toskv. I'd add a constructor in the `WindowService` code with a nullable parameter, so in the tests you could send a mock object with the methods you want to test.

Comment: Thank you very much toskv and @sebaferreras. I understand it better now. Is it also possible to write custom setters/getters for localStorage?

Comment: @AkilanArasu everything is possible! :) there's nothing stopping you from adding other methods/getters/setters to that service.

Comment: @AkilanArasu as a matter of design though, I'd make a separate service for local storage. I also bet someone already made one. ;)

Comment: @AkilanArasu just the first google search https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120135/discussion-between-akilan-arasu-and-toskv).