# Ionic 2 How to use Cordova events pause resume

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I am surprised to not find any thread already created on that topic.

In Ionic 2 there is the lifecycle of the pages in [NavController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/): `ionView[didLoad|didLeave|...]`

And there are the [Cordova events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) that are supposed to be called like this:
 `document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);`

I am in a situation where I want to get the Cordova events. Ionic lifecylce of pages is not a fit because what I want to do need to happen when the device gets in the `onResume` status whichever page shows on.

**I haven't tried it yet, because I was hoping to find a good lead here before to keep on going**, but I have the feeling that `document` won't be accessible from Angular2, Ionic2 and that I will probably will have to add a service to access the `window` like it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767595/accessing-window-object-in-ionic-2-angular-2-beta-10).

Or is there anyother known way to access `document.addEventListener(...)` when in Ionic 2?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The way it works in Ionic 2 is detailed [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#resume)

Basically, you need to inject the `Platform` instance in your page and subscribe to the `pause` event emitter:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class AppPage {
  private onResumeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.onResumeSubscription = platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
       // do something meaningful when the app is put in the foreground
    }); 
  } 

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // always unsubscribe your subscriptions to prevent leaks
    this.onResumeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: I won't try it right now but this seems correct and documented so I validate the answer.

Comment: What can I do while it is paused? As in what is the point of pause and resume?

Comment: @SR1 you can change a route, or if your app has a PIN to unlock it, you cand use it on resume (like some banking apps do, etc)

Answer (score 7):

I was also able to get document.addEventListener working from the constructor method of an Ionic2 page e.g.

```
  document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
    // do something
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
    // do something
  }, true);
```

Comment: Does nothing in the browsers though, so fairly useless.