# ionic 3 detecting when user is back from inAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-native

i have an angular ionic 3 app and using inAppBrowser plugin to launch a link from the ion-button in my app.

i want to change the title of the button but only once the user retrun back to the app.

the current code is like:
**HTML:**

```
<ion-col>
    <button ion-button clear small color="danger" icon-left (click)="openUrl(item, item.buttonModel.url)">
        <ion-icon name='{{item.buttonModel.icon}}'></ion-icon>
        <h2>{{item.buttonModel.title}}</h2>
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

**JS:**

```
openUrl(item, url) {
    //alert('launching:' + url);
    this.iab.create(url, "_system", "location=yes");
    item.showActions = true;
}
```

so specifically, i want to flip the value of showActions only after i return back from the browser.

Comment: ok found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437537/ionic-2-how-to-use-cordova-events-pause-resume

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that an exit event fires when 'iab' closes.
Seems as it you need to attach another listener.
See [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowseraddeventlistener)
So the eventname is 'exit'
 in that listener function, either:

- change item.buttonModel.title
- Or Maybe add 
  `<h2 #btn>` and
  `@ViewChild('#btn', {read:ElementRef})  el:ElementRef`
  You can then set `el.innerText`...