# How to know that ionic app going to closed or killed in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Is there any way to know that our ionic app is getting closed or killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `pause` event of the [Ionic platform service](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/). The docs describe the pause event like this:

> The pause event emits when the native platform puts the application
>   into the background, typically when the user switches to a different
>   application.

David M. gave a good answer on how to implement this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857192/5730444):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class AppPage {
  private onPauseSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.onPauseSubscription = platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
       // do something when the app is put in the background
    }); 
  } 

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // always unsubscribe your subscriptions to prevent leaks
    this.onPauseSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

First of all, you'll have to inject the `Platform` service into your page/component and then you can subscribe to the `pause` event. I only edited Davids code sample slightly, so please give him some credit.

---

Ionics Platform service is merely a wrapper around Cordovas events. So if you're further interested, check out the Cordova docs on [events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) or the [pause event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause).